# Echoing PHP Class Properties

Tags: php

can somebody explain to me why the property $message is null before the method 'getMessage'?

I was expecting it to return 'this is a message' but it returns null, it only returns a string once I reset it in the method.

Cheers

```
<?php

class Data {
    public $message = 'this is a message';

    public function getMessage() {
        return $this->$message = 'new value';
    }
}

$object = new Data;

var_dump($object->$getMessage); // Equals Null

echo $object->getMessage(); // Equals 'New value'
```

Comment: what you're trying to var_dump isn't a property - the property is message. Think you meant to try var_dump($object->message)

Comment: If you want to access the property, use its name `$object->message`, or if you want to use the method (the getter), `$object->getMessage()`. Difference is, one is a method and one is a property.

Answer (score 3):

There is no variable `$getMessage` defined, yet you're trying to use it as though it was a property name; so of course it can't return anything

If you assigned a value to $getMessage, e.g.

```
$getMessage = 'message';
```

then using

```
$object->$getMessage
```

will treat this as `$object->message` (like a variable variable) to point to the `message` property

---

Then in your `getMessage()` method, you have

```
return $this->$message = 'new value';
```

which will use the value of the variable `$message` (which isn't defined) and use it like a variable variable again to set a property named by that (non-existent) value.

---

To reference the `message` properties in the class, it's `$this->message`, not `$this->$message`

Comment: nice - didn't know PHP supported that :)

Comment: My bad I meant to $message. If I do echo $object->$message I get nothing. I take it that's because I didn't return it? Do you have to return properties aswell as functions?

Comment: no just drop the $ - $object->message is what you want

Comment: @RobGudgeon - PHP supports variable properties in that way, but it isn't recommended uness yur code makes it very clear that is what you're doing.... it's very easy fr anybody reading the code to miss that extra `$` and not understand what it's doing

Answer (score 1):

```
class Data {
    public $message = 'this is a message';

    public function getMessage() {
        return $this->message = 'new value'; // Access internal variable $message
    }
}

$object = new Data;

var_dump($object->message); // Equals 'this is a message'
echo $object->getMessage(); // Equals 'new value'
```

Answer (score 0):

`getMessage` is not a property its a method, similar to a function, you can't output a function.

you can read more about properties [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).

here a quick example of using properties and methods:

```
<?php 

 class example {

  // this is a property 
  public $a = 10;
  // this is a private property
  // private properties cannot be accessed outside the object
  private $b = 15;    

  // this is a method 
  public function sum(Int $a, Int $b) : Int
  {
      return $a + $b;
  }

  // this is a method to get the private propery 
  public function getB() : Int 
  {
     return $this->b;
  }

  }

  $obj = new example();
  // note you don't put '$' before the property name
  $a   = $obj->a;
  //$b   = $obj->b; // this will cause an error !    
  $b   = $obj->getB(); // works ! 
  $sum = $obj->sum($a,$b); // works !  
  echo $sum;
```